# How to add noise to background image?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, image

I made a  video in blender. It is basically a short clip with an animated character and a still background image. I am rendering with Cycles and I have set the render seed to be generated for each frame separately. However, I feel like my video seems faker, just because, contrary to the character, there is no noise in the background image. Is there a way to add noise to the background image and to make it change every frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a texture in the properties window:

[image]

To add the texture in the compositor use an input>texture node, and select the texture you've just created:

[image]

Then overlay that on to the background image. You can control the size and shaprpness of the noise by adding a value node and a blur node.

[image]
(click on the image to enlarge)

To make it change from frame to frame you can keyframe the values.

Another note: try other forms of noise like Clouds, Musgrave or Stucci to find the texture pattern that matches that of your rendered model's